# Sas SQL insert into (Proc SQL)

Tags: sas, sas-macro

How to apply an `insert` into `table1` from `table2`, knowing that `table1` contains more columns than `table2`? I want to make a condition if the column exists I insert, otherwise I put empty

```
proc sql; 
insert into tab1 select *, (the other columns, I want to put empty) 
from tab 2;
 quit;
```

I have 77 variables in the table

Comment: [Posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English](/help/non-english-questions). Do not post bilingual posts either, or irrelevant info (of course you want a response, you wouldn't have posted otherwise). Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get acquainted with the site's rules.

Comment: Please update the question to more completely explain what you need.  For example you have mentioned excluding some of the variables. You have also indicated that there are multiple datasets and not just two.  Is there any reason why you would want to use SQL to do this instead of using normal SAS code?

Comment: hi Tom sorry for the delay, yes I want to repeat this action on 23 table, I want to insert in table 1 all tables 2 to 23

Comment: I want to repeat this program with tables 2 to 23 to insert into table 1 :   proc sql noprint;
select nliteral(name) into :varlist separated by ','
   from dictionary.columns
   where libname='WORK' and memname='TABLE2'
;
insert into table1(&varlist) select &varlist from table2;
quit;

Comment: i hope i am clear this time?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to tell the INSERT statement which variables in the target you want to write into.

```
insert into table1(var1,var3,var4) select var1,var3,var4 from table2;
```

Any unnamed variable in the target dataset will automatically have missing values for the inserted observations.

If you need perhaps you could query the metadata to generate a list of variables that exist in the source dataset to help generate the code for you.  If the list is less than 64K bytes long you can store it into a single macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
select nliteral(name) into :varlist separated by ','
   from dictionary.columns
   where libname='WORK' and memname='TABLE2'
;
insert into table1(&varlist) select &varlist from table2;
quit;
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback but we assume that table1 contains (var1,var2,var3,var4,var5) on the other hand table2 contains (var1,var2,var3) how can I do in this case to insert only the data var1 and var2 in the table 1 and we put the others empty

Comment: in table 2 there is a variable that I want to eliminate in the macro, how can I do that in the macro, I want to repeat this operation on tables from 2 to 23, and the base table is table 1

Comment: If you don't want to include a variable in the list of variables then just don't include it.  Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: If you want to generate the list of variables but exclude some of them then augment the WHERE clause.  `where libname='WORK' and memname='TABLE2' and upcase(name) ne 'VAR3'`

Comment: Thank You for your reponse , I want to repeat this operation on tables from 2 to 23, and the base table is table 1

Comment: proc sql noprint;
select nliteral(name) into :varlist separated by ','
   from dictionary.columns
   where libname='WORK' and memname='TABLE2,TABLE3,TABLE4.........23'
;
insert into table1(&varlist) select &varlist from table2,table3,table4.......23;
quit;

Comment: A dataset name cannot contain a comma. Do you really want to do a cartesian product of 23 tables?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use SQL? If not PROC APPEND does that automatically.

```
proc append base = table1 data=table2 force;
run;
```

Comment: And you can add the DROP= dataset option to eliminate the unwanted VAR2 variable from TABLE2.